# bxSlider not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, slider, bxslider

bxSlider is not working on IE10, it is working fine in IE8 and IE9,
it is working on IE10 on mode:'fade' but not working on 'horizontal' all mode of bxSlider are working on Mozilla and Chrome. 
Where is Problem
My Code for use bxSlider is

```
 $('#slidesfMovieShowcase').bxSlider({
            mode: 'horizontal',
            controls: false,
            pager: true,
            autoHover: true,
            auto: true
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is outdated a bit but very similar code is working for me in ie10 but inside jQuery ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slidesfMovieShowcase').bxSlider({
        mode: 'horizontal',
        controls: false,
        pager: true,
        autoHover: true,
        auto: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IE10 is very picky on HTML errors.

as the first answer says, it should run inside a

> $(document).ready(function() {

Some people experience the first image not loaded with a IE10 which freaks me out.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is different:

I work with IE8/9/10 and also the

```
$(document).ready(...)
```

wasn't good; it doesn't work fine 5 times over 10! :(

At now, I've tried to put the bxslider code inside a

```
$(window).bind('load', function(){})
```

snippet and it works well 9 times over ten ...

You could try this approach ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed just removing the defer attribute.

Also you want to make sure to include the library first and then put your script

Before - this did not work in IE and Edge

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.1/jquery.bxslider.min.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 850,
            auto:true,
            pause:3500,
            useCSS:true
        });
    });
</script>
```

After - this works in IE and Edge

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.1/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 850,
            auto:true,
            pause:3500,
            useCSS:true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve my issue by downgrade the bxslider from **v4.2.12 to v4.1**